# Sign extension of single-bit constant literals in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, ieee

SystemVerilog has unsized single-bit value literals such as `'0` and `'1`.
According to the IEEE Std 1800, in 5.7.1 Integer literal constants,
I see "an unsized single-bit value ... shall be treated as unsigned."
However, Example 5 in the section, I also see:

```
logic [15:0] a, b, c, d;
a = '0;    // sets all 16 bits to 0
b = '1;    // sets all 16 bits to 1
...
```

Doesn't it mean `'1` is treated as signed?

In fact, I get the following result with `'1` and `1'b1` by Quartus Prime and ModelSim-Altera.

```
logic [3:0] a, b;
assign a = '1;    // => yields 4'b1111
assign b = 1'b1;  // => yields 4'b0001
```

I think both `'1` and `1'b1` themselves are unsigned.  Why do I see such difference?

Answer (score 1):

I missed the description "All bits of the unsized value shall be set to the value of the specified bit." in the same section.  In multiple-bit context, `'1` is treated as a sequence of all 1, but still is treated as unsigned.

So, in 4-bit context, `'1` is unsigned `4'b1111` and `1'b1` is unsigned `4'b0001`.

Sorry for bothering.

Comment: if you use `b = 1'sb1`, it will alwo yeld `1111`. This will be true sign-extension, where the top-level bit is the sign bit, even in the one-bit constants.